# delete single entries in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

let's say the following code:

```
X <- data.frame(a=c(1:12), b=(c(seq(0.5,11.5,1))), class=rep(c("1","2"), times= 6),
blubb=rep(c("a","b"), each= 6),var=rep(c("x","y","z"), each=4))
X$grp <- paste(X$class,X$blubb)

ggplot(X,aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point(aes(color= var, shape=grp), size=3) +scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,1,18,5))
```

I'd like the scale legend to only show two entries for "a" and "b", since it's kind of double, but I don't know how. If I use

```
scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,1,18,5), breaks=c(16,1), labels=c("a","b"))
```

it does not produce an Error, but it does not show the scale-legend either.

Any Ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Which error does it return?

Comment: no Error and no scale legend. I tried a combination with 'scale_shape_discrete( breaks=c(16,1), labels=c("a","b"))' but this an Error/Warning (?): 'Scale for 'shape' is already present. Adding another scale for 'shape', which will replace the existing scale.'

Comment: I think it might be a bug. But what do you try to represent? Why do you need to change the scale of the shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breaks need to represent the levels of `grp`.

From the documentation of `breaks` in `discrete_scale`:

> a character vector giving the breaks as they should appear on
>   the axis or in the legend.

```
scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 1, 18, 5), breaks = c("1 a", "1 b"), labels = c("a", "b"))
```